# Refreshing XML information in Microsoft Access?

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

*Versions XML & XSLT Version 1 and MS-Access365*

I am using XSLT to transform some XML tables which are then imported into MS-Access. The import is exactly what I need but when I save the import steps and run them later I get the following message:

> The specification failed to execute. Try re-creating the specification.

When I try to just run the import again it gives me another instance of the table (I.E. Table1 when I want the data to go into Table), and appending information doesn't work becuase I want the old data to be removed. Ideally I just want to hit Refresh and have the data updated with the XML.

I tried using the Linked Table Manager but none of the connection strings I've written are valid. Is there a solution that will allow me to refresh XML files in the same way that MS-Excel does?

Comment: Provide sample of xml and xslt files as text in question and your code. AFAIK, Access Refresh has nothing to do with table links.